# How can range both be a class and a property in VBA?

Tags: vba

In the line of code below i am going down in the vba object hierarchy and assigning the cell A1 the value 5. Since in the object browser when i click on the range class and then on the cells property, it says Property Cells As Range. I can see that cells is a property of the range class, but when it says that Property Cells as Range, does that mean that the property cells is the same as the range class? If so, how can range both be a class and a property?

Excel.Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = 5

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is to do with the fact that you can have ranges within ranges. In your example, `.Range("A1")` is a single-cell range so the cells property isn't relevant, but the most common use of the `Range.Cells` property would be in a loop:

```
Dim OuterRange as Range, InnerRange as Range 'variables
Set OuterRange = Activesheet.Range("A1:Z10")

'Example 1:
For Each InnerRange in OuterRange
    'InnerRange will be a single cell in size
    Debug.print ThisCell.Value
Next

'Example 2:
Dim a As Long
a = 1
Set InnerRange = OuterRange.Cells(a)
Do While InnerRange <> ""
    debug.print InnerRange.Formula
    a = a + 1
Loop
```

The key points this demonstrates are as follows:

- `Worksheet.Range(....)` can refer to a range of any size, including but not limited to a single-cell range
- `Worksheet.range(...).Cells(x)` refers to Cell number x within `Worksheet.Range(...)`, *as a single-cell range*. You could also use `Worksheet.Range(...).Cells.Count` to get the number of cells in the range.
- This allows you to write code that will loop through a variable range cell-by-cell no matter what the size and dimensions of the range are